# LinuxBrew directory broken

Tags: homebrew

Getting error when running the command **brew install fceux**

> E: Linuxbrew directory detected, but it seems to be broken.
>   Try to remove '/home/dileep/.linuxbrew' and try again.

Comment: Well, have you removed `/home/dileep/.linuxbrew` like the error says?

Comment: yes , its working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error may occur when you have a Linuxbrew directory but no `brew` executable in it.

That is, `/home/dileep/.linuxbrew` exists but not `/home/dileep/.linuxbrew/bin/brew`.

This shouldn’t happen, hence the error message.

The simplest way to fix this is to remove your Linuxbrew directory and [reinstall it](https://docs.brew.sh/Linuxbrew#install).